# Xtext: semantic highlighting unexpected behaviour

Tags: syntax-highlighting, default, semantics, xtext

I implemented the belowed code into MySemanticHighlightingCalculator and the color for the one element changes as expected. But the default default highlighting, like the purple color for keywords didn't work anymore.

```
INode root = resource.getParseResult().getRootNode();
        BidiTreeIterator<INode> iterator = root.getAsTreeIterable().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            INode node = iterator.next();
            if (node.getSemanticElement() instanceof ParameterDesc) {
                ParameterDesc paramdesc = (ParameterDesc) node
                        .getSemanticElement();
                if (paramdesc.isUnselected() == true) {
                    acceptor.addPosition(
                            node.getOffset(),
                            node.getLength(),
                            MySemanticHighlightingConfiguration.PARAMETER_DESCRIPTION);
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
public static final String PARAMETER_DESCRIPTION = "Parameter_Description";

public void configure(IHighlightingConfigurationAcceptor acceptor) {
    addType(acceptor, PARAMETER_DESCRIPTION, 255, 0, 0, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH);
}

public void addType(IHighlightingConfigurationAcceptor acceptor, String s,
        int r, int g, int b, int style) {
    TextStyle textStyle = new TextStyle();
    textStyle.setColor(new RGB(r, g, b));
    textStyle.setStyle(style);
    acceptor.acceptDefaultHighlighting(s, s, textStyle);
}
```

But when I remove the MySemanticHighlightingConfiguration from MyDSLUiModule, the default highlighting work again:

```
public Class<? extends IHighlightingConfiguration> bindIHighlightingConfiguration() {
        return MySemanticHighlightingConfiguration.class;
    }
```

I know that the default highlighting will not be applyed between offset and offset+length, but I want it for the rest of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your highlighting configuration has to extend the `DefaultHighlightingConfiguration` and you have to invoke `super.configure()`. That will do the trick.

Please note that `resource.getParseResult()` may be null in some rare situations.